# Retrieve Google analytics historical data of sunsetting Google Analytics Services SDK

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-firebase

Since Google sunsetting the Google Analytics Services SDKs, i have created new App + Web property with firebase sdk for my mobile app. But how can i retain complete historical data of old property so that i can view customized reports & insights in future.
Is there any option to import them to newly created property?
Since Google mentioned that "service is fully turned down in February 2020", What is the way to maintain them?